# How can I access the prototype functions?

Tags: javascript

I found code similar to this in a legacy app:

```
var Example = function (var1, var2, var3) {
   this.prop1 = var1;
   this.prop2 = var2;
   this.prop3 = var3
};

Example.prototype = function () {
   var showAlert = function (message) {
       alert(message);
   }
};

var example = new Example(null, null, null);
```

So I tried to access the prototype method like this:

```
    example.showAlert("hello");
```

Here is the jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/64dkjke1/

It doesn't work . . . the showAlert method is undefined.  The prototype is equal to a function that defines other functions inside . . . hopefully I'm just overlooking something simple here.

How can I access this prototype function?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure the function assigned to the prototype isn't instead returning an object and being executed in the actual code? I think you just misinterpreted the code you were looking at when building this example.

Comment: In it's current state, it is impossible to access `showAlert` outside of the function you are assigning to the prototype.

Comment: Thank you Kevin.  I don't doubt I misinterpreted what I was looking at.  I was wondering why what I was trying wasn't working, but I believe you answered that with your second comment.  Thank you.

Comment: Cannot understand why people downvote this. The question is actually not bad and requires quite some understanding of how prototypes work etc. Take my upvote at least @codenewbie

Comment: I can understand why the downvote.  In an effort to condense the code to post it, I had overlooked something:  `Example.prototype = function () {
    var showAlert = function (message) {
        alert(message);
    },
    Init = function () {
        //whatever gets initialized
    };

    return {
        init: Init
    };
}`  had I seen this, there probably would be no post.  Updated jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/64dkjke1/3/  (Sry, had some trouble figuring out the edit feature here)

Comment: Which, in turn, made the question unclear (hence the downvote.) If you edited the question and corrected it to show a proper example it would no longer be unclear. Unfortunately, that will render a few of the existing answers incorrect, though, i guess that's what people get for answering an unclear question!

Answer (score 3):

If you have no problem changing the original code, you can do the following to have the prototype receive an object using [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression):

```
Example.prototype = (function () {
    return {
        showAlert : function (message) {
            alert(message);
        }
    }
})();

var example = new Example(null, null, null);

example.showAlert("hello");
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/64dkjke1/1/)

Comment: It would be nice if downvoters explained what's wrong with this.

Comment: I saw that the actual prototype function I was looking at returned 2 functions, which would become public, and all of the other functions it defined would be private unless I exposed them as in your example.  I knew I overlooked something.  It is thousands of lines long, so I reduced the amount of code, and in doing so I missed that key point.Thank you.

Comment: I cannot understand the downvoting aswell. One could argue that you did not show how to call the prototype without changing the sourcecode, but as I pointed out in my answer even doing that makes none sense so to me your answer deserves my upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Was it like this instead, attaching an object to the prototype? It's difficult to determine what the issue is because you say that the code you've posted is only *similar* to the code in the legacy app, so we can't really know for sure.

```
Example.prototype = {
  showAlert: function (message) {
    alert(message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, it's structurally similar to what I posted, but thousands of lines longer.  What I presented was a scaled down version for the purposes of asking how to access one of the methods that the prototype adds.  What I missed was that at the very bottom of this prototype function, only 2 functions are returned.  So 2 functions were made public, all the rest are private.  I have a better understanding of this now.  Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, cause

```
var showAlert = function (message) {
     alert(message);
 }
```

is private.

you can do this:

```
function abc(){
 var myPrivateVar = "Hello";
  this.alert = function(){
    alert(myPrivateVar);
  }
}
new abc().alert();
```

but not this

```
var a = new abc();
alert(a.myPrivateVar);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access the function  `showAlert()` (as you have already figured out)
 The reason for this is simple.

```
Example.prototype = function ()
```

Does not extend your prototype by a function but **overrides** the whole prototype (which you usually don't want to do unless you are very aware of what you're doing). In JavaScript the prototype of a class is a function itself. You have access to your prototype by calling `myClass.prototype` which will return your prototype object. 

 The prototype can be extended (like every other object in JavaScript aswell) 
quick example:

```
Example.prototype.showAlert = function(message){ alert(message); };
```

now you could call:

```
Example.prototype.showAlert("Hi");
// or calling it from an instance of Example:
var myExample = new Example();
myExample.showAlert("Hi")
```

So what your fiddle does is it replaces the whole prototype with this:

```
function () {
    var showAlert = function (message) {
        alert(message);
    }
};
```

One could argue that this new function does not serve well as a prototype, but still **IS** callable (to come back to your original question). You can call it like this:

```
 Example.prototype()
```

But nothing will happen since the only thing happening in this function is that it will declare a 'private' function inside this prototype-scope, which never gets called.

```
// start of prototype function
var showAlert = function (message) {
        alert(message);
    }
// end of prototype function
```

I cannot imagine this is what your intention was, so my advice is to stick to extending prototypes (but even that only if you have to).

Comment: Good job on the extra explanation.